# Define a base url in Backbone.js router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to be able to specify a base url for all my routes for development. Some of the devs have machines setup to work out of subdirectories instead of the application sitting at the webroot.
I would like to only define these routes once.
Instead of:
    routes: {
        "toms-subdirectory/users": "init_users"
    }
I would like:

```
routes: {
    "/users": "init_users"
}
```

and be able to specify a baseurl for that installation so I could easily make it work across installs.

Right now I'm forcing them by defining a route object using bracket syntax to keep the dynamic keys and assigning that to the routes property inside the route. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way.

```
my_routes = {};
my_routes[window.webroot + '/users'] = 'init_users';

MyRoute = Backbone.Router.extend({ routes: my_routes })
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [Backbone.history.start](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) like this

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: "/public/search/"
});
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Strange, I thought I had tried this. Thanks.