# Meteor using backbone for routing always loading one route

Tags: backbone.js, meteor

I'd appreciate any insight into whether this is a "correct" way of doing things and also what's causing the error I'm seeing.

I have added backbone to my base meteor install  `meteor add backbone`

Then I set up a `router.js` file as follows (just showing 2 pages as example);

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "":                 "index", 
    "help":             "help",  
    ... 
  },

  index: function() {
    Session.set('currentPage', 'homePage');
  },

  login: function() {
    Session.set('currentPage', 'loginPage');
  },

  ...
```

Then for the pages I have html files with templates looking something like this...

```
<template name="homepage">
    {{#if route}}
    You're at the Home Page!
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Then for the main page I have an html file that contains the following;

```
<body> 
...
    {{> homepage}}
    {{> loginpage}} 
    {{> helppage}}
...
</body>
```

This works for all of the pages except the one designated 'homepage', this template is *always* rendered regardless of where I am on the site.  e.g. myapp/ as the root page just displays the homepage template, but myapp/loginpage displays the loginpage template and the homepage template.  So every single page displays the contest of the homepage template.

Any insight? (or better ways to structure).

Thank you

Comment: After typing all that out and thinking about it I'm imagining it's because the "" matches the root url of my site, and so that it returns you're on the "index" page no matter where you are on the site.  If that is the case, is there a way around that?  I would have imagined having the session variable set not to 'homePage' should fix that.

Comment: You may have to define your initial/base url in the backbone history start. Look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368151/define-a-base-url-in-backbone-js-router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally a question that I can answer because it's what I've been doing 60 hours a week at work for the last few months :-P

You're doing a few things wrong here, and they're extremely simple fixes that will get you fired up in no time.

### First thing

You need to instantiate *all* of your routers and then initialize `Backbone.pushState()`.

```
// This is just how I have been doing it, there are many correct ways.
var LoadedRouters = {
    Module1 : new Module1Router(),
    Module2 : new Module2Router(),
    ...
};
// After all routes instantiated, we tell Backbone to start listening.
Backbone.history.start({ pushState : true, root : "/" });
```

It's **very important** that you set the `root` property correctly, or else weird things start happening.

### Second thing

You **HAVE TO** list your routers from the **most**-specific to the **least**-specific, *top-down*. The URL structure you outlined above will **ALWAYS** match the first route and trigger it.

```
routes : {
    "help/phones/newservice" : HandleNewServiceHelp(),
    "help/phones/oldservice" : HandleOldServiceHelp(),
    "help/phones(/:any)" : HandleAllPhoneHelp(),
    "help(/:any)" : HandleAllHelp(),
    "" : HandleAllUnmatchedRoutes()
};
```

`Backbone.router` can be a tricky thing to learn.

Comment: So, first and second thing, then what Kate did?

Comment: For the most part, yes. The code snippet in `Second Thing` is merely a map of the routes that the router matches, and represents the `Router.routes` property of whatever Router it lives inside. Also contained within that router are functions `HandleNewServiceHelp`, `HandleOldServiceHelp`, `HandleAllPhoneHelp`, `HandleAllHelp`, and `HandleAllUnmatchedRoutes`. All methods supplied as the route action inside the `routes` mapping need to have an identically-named function inside the same router. **The functions DO NOT map to functions outside the router.** (I think.)